# 2018 Macbook Pro 3 Display Set Up - HOW?

Tags: mac, display

New to the forum. I bought a Macbook Pro last year. It has 2 USBC ports. I'd like to set up a 3 monitor system for my home office.

Looking for the least amount of adapters and plugs. I am envisioning plugging my mac in while it's closed and having the display pop up on 3 screens side by side as extended displays and not mirror.

Is this possible? If so, what's the easiest adapter or docking station to pull this off? Also, anyone have suggestions on a 3 monitor holding stand and 3 monitors? I just use basic programs for work, so basic monitors will be fine. I do not watch videos.

Comment: What is your budget?  What exact model do you have?  The specifications on apple.com says how the monitors can be connected.

Comment: Maybe a USB C splitter/adapter?